# How to group dataframe by Conditioning in R

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, filter, group

I want to group a data frame by using a condition which when applied gives the ouptut "True False False False False True False False True False ..." and so on. I want group in a way which gives me the rows from "True" to the last "False" i.e. for the mentioned output I´d get 3 groups (the rows which give) "True False False False False", "True False False " and "True False"

I hope this makes sense lol

Answer (score 2):

We could do this by counting the cumulative number of TRUE's and using that as our group.

```
a <- data.frame(log = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))

a %>% 
  mutate(group = cumsum(log))
```

or in base R:

```
a$group = cumsum(a$log)
```

Result

```
     log group
1   TRUE     1
2  FALSE     1
3  FALSE     1
4  FALSE     1
5  FALSE     1
6   TRUE     2
7  FALSE     2
8  FALSE     2
9   TRUE     3
10 FALSE     3
```